# JQM 1.4 Scroll "hanging" on iOS7

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios7, scroll, mobile-safari

Scrolling down hangs on iOS 7 Safari or Chrome. The first time you try to scroll down it hangs. Then, when you try a second time it works just fine.

Try to scroll with the following page on iPhone or iPhone Simulator to trigger the problem:

[www.mycoursewalk.com](http://www.mycoursewalk.com)

Using JQM 1.4.

Comment: Are you using any plugin with JQM?

Comment: I'm not using any plugins.

Comment: test it without google ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Google AdSense banner in the JQM footer. Without the ad in the footer, the scrolling is smooth again. THanks for the tip Omar!